# Can you use data POSTED from AJAX in SQL SELECT query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hi have the below ajax submit data to the URL. I have retrieved the data in my PHP files and I want to write a SQL query to select data WHERE data equals submitted data.

See Below -

```
  function loadJobRequests() {


      //AJAX code to submit form.
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8888/EduSubOct/json-data- 
        jobrequests.php",
        data: { userEmail: localStorage.getItem("email")} , 
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            alert("Information Entered Successfully");

        }
    });
}
```

PHP SQL -

include_once 'dbh.php';

```
//Here we fetch the data from the URL that was passed from our HTML 
   form
   $userEmail = $_POST['userEmail'];

   $sql =  "SELECT * FROM jobRequest WHERE email='$userEmail'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Can anyone advise me if this is the correct way of using SELECT query with AJAX POST data.

Comment: Your code appears to be ok BUT there are a couple of problems. First, you don't check the value coming from localstorage (has it been set, is it a valid value). Secondly, again no data validation on the incoming data (see Johnny Drop Tables - https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

change the SQL statement from

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM jobRequest WHERE email='$userEmail'";
```

to

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM jobRequest WHERE email='".$userEmail."'";
```

and always try to check if the value is set or not, there are times when no value was sent and your php script will generate an error. so your whole code would be

```
if (isset( $_POST['userEmail'])) {
    $userEmail = $_POST['userEmail'];

    $sql =  "SELECT * FROM jobRequest WHERE email='".$userEmail."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

Comment: This answer  seems like what I need however it still is not working for me.